# Dynamically build a filter expression for the Where() method in LINQ to entities

Tags: .net, linq, entity-framework-core

I have an Entity model that I am trying to use to execute a query that would translate to SQL that looks like this:

```
Select * from illustrations where 
(agency = “00057” or ((agency = “00057” and writingcode = “000YM549”) || (agency = “00057” and writingcode = “000YM879”)))
and Risklevel in (“HIGH”, “LOW”, “OK”) and risksToEvaluate = “OFFSET TEST AGE” and anniversaryDateFromDate between ‘01/01/2021’ and ‘12/01/2021’ 
order by riskLevel desc
```

The model and the LINQ query is simple enough, however my problem is I won't get all of the filter values all the time.  I might get all, a subset of them, or none.  So I need to build a filter to pass to the Where() clause dynamically.  Does EF Core provide a way to do this?  I know I can chain where clauses like Where(filter1).Where(filter2), etc, but that chains together with Ands.  Is there a way I can chain them together via AND or OR as needed?

Comment: No, it doesn't. And it's not their job. Seek SO/internet for "predicate builder", there are a lot of examples.

Comment: Side note: The logic here is unclear (as well as the syntax). `(agency = “00057” or ((agency = “00057” and writingcode = “000YM549”) || (agency = “00057” and writingcode = “000YM879”)))` can be reduced to `agency = “00057”`, and the dates are ambiguous.